# iOS7 present childViewController similar to MFMailComposeViewController for iPad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, segue, childviewcontroller

One of the view controllers in my iPad app is a questionnaire form. I'm trying to present it so that it appears in a childViewController modal segue just like the default segue for MFMailComposeViewController.

This is the look I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The code I am using doesn't seem to be working:

```
AskQuestionViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AskQuestionViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self.splitViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Why are you adding it as a child? What, specifically, doesn't work?

Comment: Whenever I run my code it crashes. I am trying to achieve the same modal segue that is the default for when you present a MFMailComposeViewController. It is my understanding that the way to achieve this is to add it is a childviewcontroller. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Don't add it as a child and give details of the exception (stack trace and message).

Comment: When I don't add it as a child it does a modal segue just fine but I'm trying to achieve this overlay segue look like the one in the image instead.  Whenever you present a MFMailComposeViewController view controller you get that look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
AskQuestionViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AskQuestionViewController"];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self.splitViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It works!  When I first tried it I put it as a modalTransitionStyle instead of a modalPresentationStyle.  I can't believe how easy it was. Thanks!